# I want to change position of close button in drawer of ant design. By default it is left but i want to change it to right

Tags: reactjs, drawer, ant-design-pro

So, I am using ant design drawer and the close button in drawer is on left side by default. I want it on right side.

```
`.ant-drawer-close {
  right: 0 !important;
  left: unset !important;
}`
`
```

I tried this but it didn't work. Please, somebody help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found solution of this myself.

After playing around sometime I found this solution.

```
.ant-drawer-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
}
```

In this, I am setting the position to absolute and giving top and right side some space. You can adjust the space according to you.